# comboBox selected value change

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to give the customer an option to choose a city from COMBOBOX, and once the city's chosen, a list of that city's streets should be in COMBOBOX2. I tried the following code and I got an error, during the first run, maybe someone can explain this to me?

```
private void Search_by_Apartment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Cities> city = DAL.cities();
        cmBxCity.DataSource = city;//Here he ran the second function, why?
        cmBxCity.DisplayMember = "city";
        cmBxCity.ValueMember = "cityID";
    }

    private void cmBxCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Streets> street = DAL.streets(Convert.ToInt32(cmBxCity.SelectedText));
        // List<Streets> street = DAL.streets(Convert.ToInt32(cmBxCity.SelectedValue));
        comBxStreet.DataSource = street;
        comBxStreet.DisplayMember = "street";
        //cmBxCity.ValueMember = "cityID";

    }
```

Comment: What was the error you received?  Is there a reason you are using SelectedText instead of SelectedValue to select your streets?

Comment: @Brettski , yes Because the value get "" ,I don't know way ? and SelectedValue get string it is also not good what I nedd to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired whenever the selected index is changed programatically or by the user.

As Davide Pirsa points out, when you change the DataSource of cmBxCity, you are programatically changing the selected index, hence firing the 'cmBxCity.SelectedIndexChanged' event at this line:

```
cmBxCity.DataSource = city;//Here he ran the second function, why?
```

One possible solution is to use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead, which is only fired for changes made by the user.

Answer (score 0):

when you assign the `DataSource` of the `cmBxCity` control its selectedItem changes from nothing to one item and this triggers the event handler `cmBxCity_SelectedIndexChanged`.

in the question you are talking about COMBOBOX and COMBOBOX2 but in the code there is only one control which is: `cmBxCity`.

shouldn't you show the streets in the second control called: `cmBxStreet` ?

Comment: You are right. How do I do he will not come for the first time to the cmBxCity_SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: yes but is it clear now for you why second method triggers when you assign the datasource?

Comment: and you surely should convert to Int32 the cityID and NOT the CityName, so the correct one to use in the second method is this: Convert.ToInt32(cmBxCity.SelectedValue), but only when cmBxCity.SelectedValue != null and cmBxCity.SelectedIndex >=0